# Is there a symbol for matrix multiplication operator?

Tags: matrices, notation

Title says it all.

Is there any specific operator symbol for matrix multiplication?

Not just write down side by side but symbols like cross ($\times$).

Comment: Ehm, just a small dot perhaps? I just checked a book for you and that's what they do. Sometimes when matrices are given capital letters, they don't write anything, so AB implies matrix multiplication A times B

Comment: I don't think using multiplication operator is necessary.  You can write the product of matrices altogether without the operation.  For instance, $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: It is usually implicit.

Comment: I'm asking the well known symbol(not just nothing), but looks like there is no such symbol. Maybe, I can just define the operator.

Comment: I wonder why there is no such symbol. Matrix multiplication is quite unusual for beginner and also it doesn't satisfy commutative law.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Juxtaposition is the standard notational convention (to "write side by side") without an intermediary operation symbol): for matrices $A, B$ on which matrix multiplication is defined, write $AB$. Some texts may use the "dot" $A\cdot B$, but juxtaposition is more typical.

See the entry in Wikipedia: [Matrix Multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) to disambiguate "standard" matrix multiplication from other matrix products: Hadamard product $A\circ B$, Frobenius product $A:B$, and Kronecker product $A\otimes B$.

You'll see the "dot" and "cross" typically used with vectors (which are, also, matrices) to distinguish between the operations of the dot product and the cross product.

Comment: "Some texts may use the "dot" A⋅B", I am interested, could you indicate some example?